# Why don't I have cgconfig service although I installed cgroup-tools?

Tags: cgroups

I am using Debian 11 Bullseye. I have installed `cgroups-tools` and I created a `cgconfig.conf` file. When I start the cgconfig servive by using:

```
sudo systemctl start cgconfig.service
```

it gives this error:

```
*Unit cgconfig.service could not be found.*
```

I checked that which services are available in `/etc/init.d`, and found that there is only the `cgroupfs-mount` service. How can I start the `cgroups` service?

Comment: See [The service cgconfig won't start because it cannot be found](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/636148/86440) for a similar question in Fedora. What do you want to use `cgconfig` for? Can’t you achieve the same goal with systemd?

Comment: Right, and systemd can manage cgroups for you.

Comment: If you no longer need this question, please click the "Delete" link under it; do not edit it into a non-question. Thank you!